# How should I recharge a two-pin/wire Li-ion pouch cell?

Tags: lithium-ion, charging

I had an old SD card MP3 Player that broke (plastic buttons popped out and stripped the membrane between them and the PCB). I managed to salvage both the mini USB connector (the connections to the board seemed to have broken from repeated use) and the LiPo cell, which is about the size of a stack of postage stamps. Unfortunately, the cell is only marked either "L9j" or "i67" (depending on rotation) on one side (although the "i/j" could be part of a faded circle), which doesn't mean anything to me. It has only red and green wires. (I'm used to cell/mobile phone batteries with three pins/wires, the third being black/orange/yellow for "charge".) Unfortunately, some of the track got stripped when I removed the USB connector, so I am unable to diagnose/trace to where the VCC line went on/through the board.

I've salvaged both a solar panel (max output of 3.3V in direct sunlight) and an on/on switch with a common pin in the middle, which I'm planning to use to connect both the cell and the charger. How I should charge the cell will determine whether the common pin is the cell's VCC or ground.

My question is this: How should I (re)charge the cell?

1. Supply a higher voltage (presumably ~4.2-4.5v) to ground than the cell's output voltage (~3.5-3.7v), using the red wire as GND for the charger.
2. Connect the charger's ground to the cell's ground and the charger's VCC to the cell's VCC through a diode and booster/logic level shifter circuit.

I don't want to blow it up or cause it to catch fire and it seems a waste to me to repurpose a rechargeable cell without being able to recharge it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, you would not apply voltage. Not directly, but with current limit. And at least not above 4.2V anyway, that is the limit of damage from overcharging.

Lithium-ion batteries need to be charged with a suitable current and voltage profile, and sensed when to stop charging. Answering how to do it is out of scope and has been asked many timed.

You would not also use red wire for ground, unless you know it is the ground wire. If it is the supply wire then it's not the ground wire.

2. No, as explained above, that's not the way to charge batteries. Not even through a diode.

If you want to charge lithium-ion batteries, buy a lithium-ion battery charging module. You can likely get multiple units with $1.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. While David's answer is simple and to the point, yours provides a little more detail. I suppose now I'm going to have to buy a Li-ion cell charger or find a schematic for one.

Answer (score 3):

You charge a single Li-ion cell  with a single-cell  Li-ion charger. Important: not a power supply, a charger. For example: [https://www.amazon.com/110V-240V-Li-ion-Battery-Charger-Connector/dp/B008H7C1B4/ref=sr_1_4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008H7C1B4)

Comment: I think this short and simple answer should be the de facto answer we can refer to the next time someone asks about lithium ion battery charging. (The charger or charging circuit still needs a power supply like 5V from USB, but that's another thing).

Comment: @Justme I've got a solar panel (~3-3.3v) that I can use, which I can connect to either a booster or logic level shifter before the charger.